Архитектура программы (на C++) которая может работать (быть скомпилирована) как с GUI (Qt) так и без него, без потери работоспособности?
Как правильно написать программу (спроектировать) (на C++) которая сможет быть скомпилирована как с графическим интерфейсом (Qt) так и без него, без потери работоспособности?
Хочется полностью отделить часть с библиотекой Qt.
Приведите минимальный пример если возможно.

может я ошибаюсь, но если программа может работать без GUI, то он ей и не нужен. А так - вынесите все что не требует интерактивного вмешательства пользователя в отдельную библиотеку и вызывайте по мере необходимости из GUI. Собственно это и есть нормальная практика - разделение интерфейса и функционала.

Выделите пользовательский интерфейс в отдельный модуль, запускаемый в дочернем процессе с  которым основная часть общается по пайпу (или через общую память и т.п.), передавая туда-обратно текстовые команды. Тогда вы можете сделать как графический (на qt или GTK или tcl/tk), так и терминальный (текстовый, например на curses) интерфейсы  в  отдельно компилируемых программах и не будете тащить специфические для интерфейса библиотеки в основной модуль

Сложно немного понять что вы имели ввиду. Если у приложения правильная архитектура то зачастую "бизнес-логику" отделяют от представления, его выделяют как ядро, но само по себе оно не будет работать. Сам графический интерфейс выступает в роли связующего звена между обычным пользователем и программой. Можно почитать например про паттерн MVC.
С другой стороны вы говорите о раздельном запуске, но раз вы хотите чтобы она работала то и подавать данные как-то надо, остается командная строка. Значит вы должны написать обработчик для работы с командной строкой.
Если взять пример, первое что пришло в голову это GIT.
У него есть множество графических интерфейсов, но можно и через командную строку работать без любый доп. утилит.
